# Performing operations before table view loads,

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitableview

I'm working on a turn-based iOS game and i am trying to write code currently to display a table of my custom cells generated from an `NSArray` of `GKTurnBasedMatches`. I have a simple question - How do i add code to a table view that will execute early enough to populate my table view? When i try it in `ViewDidLoad`, it is too late and empty. If there were an init i would stuff it in there.

Comment: Better you reload your table after your data source sets up.

Comment: Can you show your view controller code ?

Comment: You can implement delegation for that purpose, too.

Answer (score 0):

You have methods that run before viewDidLoad.

For example, the `init` method for the controller.

Comment: __viewWillAppear__ is getting called after __viewDidLoad__

Answer (score -1):

do your thing in app delegate and use it in the beginning of ViewDidLoad before all the stuff of ViewDidLoad